# Creating separate sets from file in python

Tags: python, split, set

Below is a sample input file:

```
A, B, C 
Location:London 
A, 46
B, 93
C, 32
Location:Amsterdam 
A, 83
B, 21
C, 92
Location:Paris
A, 29
B, 91
C, 10
```

The output should be as follows:

name_set = { A, B, C }
location_set = {London, Amsterdam, Paris}

Generate a dictonary that maps name to number and calculate total

```
dic = {A: 46, B: 93, C:32 , A: 83, B: 21, C: 92, A:29, B: 91, C:10}
A has 158 
B has 205 
C has 134
```

This is what I tried but I don't get above sets:

```
  name_set = set() 
    location_set = set()
    num_set = set ()
    userfile = input("Enter input file name:") 
    input_file2 = open(userfile, "r") 
    input_file = input_file2.readlines()
    name_set = input_file[0].strip().split(',')

for next_line in input_file: 
    if next_line.startswith("Location"):
        location_set = next_line.strip().split(":")[-1]
    else:
       num_set = next_line.strip().split(',')[-1]
print(name_set) 
print(location_set) 
print(num_set)

name_to_num = {} 
for k in name_set:
   for v in scores_set:
      party_to_score[k] = v
print(name_to_num)
```

Comment: This code creates some empty sets but then overwrites them with strings, e.g. `location_set = next_line.strip().split(":")[-1]`. You need to use `add()` in order to add an element to a set, e.g. `location_set.add(next_line.strip().split(":")[-1])`.

Comment: What you say you want for output doesn't make sense.  `dic = {A: 46, B: 93, C:32 , A: 83, B: 21, C: 92, A:29, B: 91, C:10}` isn't valid because it represents a dictionary with duplicate keys, which isn't supported and would likely not be what you wanted anyway.  Why are you testing for "REPORTING"?

Comment: To store those values in `dic`, you'd need to change your keys to something like `{('A', 'London'): 46, ('B', 'London'): 93, ...}`

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you want as a result, as you seem to want to produce a dictionary with duplicate keys.  This isn't supported by a standard Python dictionary, and usually isn't what you want anyway.  Just think...how would you tell Python which key value to look up in a dictionary that had duplicate keys?

Here's code that gives you the simple sets that you want by constructing a data structure to represent the input file that is easy to query and build other results from once it has been built. NOTE: this ignores the first line of the file, and will build the list of names from whatever it finds in the values for each location.

```
locations = {}
current_location = None
name_set = set()

input_file = open('/tmp/data.txt', "r")

for next_line in input_file:
    next_line = next_line.strip()
    if next_line:
        if next_line.startswith("Location"):
            location = next_line.split(":")[-1]
            current_location = locations[location] = {}
        elif current_location is not None:
            key, val = next_line.split(',')
            if key not in name_set:
                name_set.add(key)
            current_location[key] = int(val)

location_set = set(locations.keys())

print(location_set)
print(name_set)
print(locations)
```

Result:

```
{'Amsterdam', 'London', 'Paris'}
{'A', 'C', 'B'}
{'London': {'A': 46, 'B': 93, 'C': 32},
 'Amsterdam': {'A': 83, 'B': 21, 'C': 92},
 'Paris': {'A': 29, 'B': 91, 'C': 10}}
```

Then, if you want to count to total number of As, Bs and Cs, you can do this:

```
import collections

...

counts = collections.Counter()
for values in locations.values():
    counts.update(values)

 print(counts)
```

which will give you this:

```
Counter({'B': 205, 'A': 158, 'C': 134})
```

or if you want the counts in a standard dict, you can add:

```
counts = dict(counts)

print(counts)
```

to get:

```
{'A': 158, 'B': 205, 'C': 134}
```

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to create a dictionary to map A,B,C to their numbers so I could calculate a total

Comment: @AarzooArya - Keep in mind that you'll always be able to build that list as you go.  It doesn't help you to have the list of possible keys beforehand.  Having data like that is a very easy way to get strange behavior when someone fails to update the list at the top to match new data down below. If the data file is computer-generated, then that wouldn't be an issue, of course.  At that point, why not put helpful summaries of the data at the top of the file.  In general, I'd suggest that you try to avoid establishing that sort of non-DRY data in real life.